# Spring injects a list with generics issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, generics

Interface:

```
public interface PoiSearchDataProvider<T extends AbstractPoiSearchData> {

    T fetch(PoiSearchRequest poiSearchRequest) throws Exception;

}
```

If I use:

```
@Resource
private List<PoiSearchDataProvider<AbstractPoiSearchData>> poiSearchDataProviders;
```

Application fails to start: `expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.`

And it works:

```
@Resource
private List<PoiSearchDataProvider<? extends AbstractPoiSearchData>> poiSearchDataProviders;
```

I want to know the reason behind...

Answer (score 0):

Because your interface is defined as `T extends AbstractPoiSearchData`,
Then `List<PoiSearchDataProvider<AbstractPoiSearchData>>` it is declared as single `AbstractPoiSearchData` which doesn't extend itself.

I think that in your case :

```
public interface PoiSearchDataProvider<AbstractPoiSearchData> {

    AbstractPoiSearchData fetch(PoiSearchRequest poiSearchRequest) throws Exception;

}
```

Will be enough and you can use magic of the polymorphism